# EventListener de mouse não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, css

Peguei esse exemplo abaixo do livro "Eloquent Javascript" 2ª edição em português pg.184.

O objetivo é desenhar pontos na tela usando cliques: toda vez que o mouse é clicado, um ponto azul é criado onde o mouse está apontando.

Porém, além do estilo bege que é aplicado ao background, nada mais acontece.
Já revisei por erros de sintaxe e não encontro nada...
Tentei declarar o estilo no head, e também não mudou nada.

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Estilo do body, e da classe .dot-->
<style>
    body {
        height:200px;
        background:beige;
    }
    .dot{
        height:8px; width:8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: blue;
        position:absolute;
    }
</style>

<!-- Para obter informações precisas sobre o local onde aconteceu um evento do mouse você pode olhar para as
suas propriedades pageX e pageY , que contêm as coordenadas do evento(em pixels) em relação ao canto
superior esquerdo do documento. -->

<script>
    addEventListener("click", function(event){
                    var dot = document.createElement("div");
                    dot.className("dot");
                    dot.style.left = (event.pageX -4) + "px";
                    dot.style.top = (event.pageY -4) + "px";
                    document.body.appendChild(dot);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className` não é uma função, o correto seria `className = "dot"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <!-- Estilo do body, e da classe .dot-->
  <style>
    body {
      height: 200px;
      background: beige;
    }
    
    .dot {
      height: 8px;
      width: 8px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background: blue;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- Para obter informações precisas sobre o local onde aconteceu um evento do mouse você pode olhar para as
suas propriedades pageX e pageY , que contêm as coordenadas do evento(em pixels) em relação ao canto
superior esquerdo do documento. -->

  <script>
    addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      var dot = document.createElement("div");
      dot.className = "dot";
      dot.style.left = (event.pageX - 4) + "px";
      dot.style.top = (event.pageY - 4) + "px";
      document.body.appendChild(dot);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Verdade! className é uma propriedade do elemento...

Comment: Mas eu estou ouvindo "click"...  nesse trecho eu seto isso: "document.getElementById('body').addEventListener("click", function(event)". Não é?

Comment: Só corrigi o className para ="dot" e já resolveu. Obrigado!

Comment: Não sabia que se podia adicionar um ouvinte de evento a nada, respondendo e aprendendo

Comment: percebi agora que, por padrão, ao adicionar um eventListener "à ninguém", ele será adicionado à body...

Comment: Ou talvez seja adicionado ao elemento html dentro do qual o script está inserido.... Vai saber.

Comment: vocẽ pode testar tirando a tag `<body>`, se ainda funcionar significa que o evento não é adicionado a essa tag específica, mas acredito que, quando não é especificado, todas as tag recebem o ouvinte de evento, não tenho certeza disso, mas se for verdade é algo ruim, já que gasta muito recursos adicionando onde não precisa e pode ocorrer efeitos indesejados (criar pontos onde não deveria)

Comment: Mesmo sem a tag <body> funciona.

Comment: Segundo esse mesmo livro "Eloquent Javascritp", quando adicionamos um eventListener a objeto nenhum, é o o objeto DOM window que o recebe. Ou seja, o objeto pai de tudo que incluímos na tela... de todas as tags não é?

Comment: Não saberia lhe responder, se já tiver uma pergunta relacionada a isso, você pode criar uma para falar sobre "adição de ouvintes de evento a nada"